# Manual cache blocking and Intel Optimization Flags

Tags: fortran, tiling

I'm trying to test the effectiveness of a manual cache blocking or loop tiling optimization that has been applied on some Fortran scientific code routine. Concerning Tile Size Selection, I used an algorithm based on classical Distinct Lines Estimation. I am using Intel Fortran Compiler ifort 13.0.0 (2012)

To observe some Execution Time speed-up, I have to switch `-O2` optimization flag (there IS a 10% of speed-up between -O2 code WITH manual cache blocking and `-O2` code without manual cache blocking). If I set `-O3 or -O3 -xHost`, then the Execution Time remain unimproved (more or less equal to the Execution Time of the base code without manual cache blocking, compiled with `-O3 -xHost`).

Notice that vectorization is present only with `-O3 -xHost` compiler flags. But with only `-O3` still I can't observe any `speed-up`. SO the question is:

*What are the optimization(s) that are actually interfering with the manual cache blocking at O2?*

Here there is the Intel HLO (High Level Optimizer) report of an `-O3` only compilation of the manually tiled code:

```
HLO REPORT LOG OPENED ON Mon Mar  5 10:41:19 2018


</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;-1:-1;hlo;traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
High Level Optimizer Report (traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_)
Unknown loop at line #346
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 226
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 232
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 251
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 251
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 254
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 254
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 254
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 254
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 254
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 254
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 257
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 257
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 276
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 277
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 296
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 296
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 296
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 296
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 313
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 314
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 325
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 325
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 325
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 325
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 361
Perfect Nest of depth 3 at line 361
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 361
Adjacent Loops: 3 at line 361
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 361
Perfect Nest of depth 3 at line 361
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 361
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 374
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 377
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 377
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 377
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 377
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 378
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 378
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 382
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 382
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 382
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 382
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 382
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 382
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 382
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 400
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 400
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 401
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 401
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 402
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 402
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 406
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 407
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 408
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 412
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 412
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 416
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 416
Perfect Nest of depth 2 at line 417
QLOOPS 246/246/0    ENODE LOOPS 246 unknown 1 multi_exit_do 0 do 245 linear_do 233 lite_throttled 0
LINEAR HLO EXPRESSIONS:  1900 / 5384 + LINEAR(innermost): 1628 / 5384
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;200:200;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 200=9

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;216:216;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 216=4
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 216=1

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;239:239;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 239=1

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;267:267;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 267=1

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;281:281;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 281=3

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;289:289;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 289=1

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;301:301;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 301=1

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;318:318;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 318=3

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;330:330;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 330=3

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;352:352;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 352=1
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 352=1

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;361:361;hlo_distribution;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
LOOP DISTRIBUTION in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 361
Estimate of max_trip_count of loop at line 361=12
Estimate of max_trip_count of loop at line 361=12
Estimate of max_trip_count of loop at line 361=12
Estimate of max_trip_count of loop at line 361=12

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;365:365;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 365=1

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;389:389;hlo_scalar_replacement;in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 389=1
#of Array Refs Scalar Replaced in traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_ at line 389=1

Loop dual-path report:

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;179:179;hlo;traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
Loop at 179 -- selected for multiversion- Assume shape array stride tests
Loop at 179 -- selected for multiversion- Assume shape array stride tests
Loop at 179 -- selected for multiversion- Assume shape array stride tests

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;184:184;hlo;traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
Loop at 184 -- selected for multiversion- Assume shape array stride tests
Loop at 188 -- selected for multiversion- Assume shape array stride tests

</users/home/mc28217/dev_HPC_Gyre_benchmark_test_trunk_2/NEMOGCM/CONFIG/GYRE_BENCHMARK_BLKD/BLD/ppsrc/nemo/traadv_fct.f90;190:190;hlo;traadv_fct_mp_tra_adv_fct_;0>
Loop at 190 -- selected for multiversion- Assume shape array stride tests
```

Based on these results from `opt-report`, I tried to completely disable the scalar replacement optimization and I managed to remove loop fusion with a compiler directive from the various loops. Despite this attempt, I cannot see any difference.

What could be the interfering optimization introduced by `-O3`?

Some information: Because for license reasons I cannot post code. I have thirteen 3D loops, and based on the Distinct Lines Estimation analysis, I tiled the centermost loop of every loop nest.

EDIT: This is a loop nest example:

```
DO jk = 2, jpkm1
    DO jltj = 1, jpj, OBS_UPSTRFLX_TILEY    
        DO jj = jltj, MIN(jpj, jltj+OBS_UPSTRFLX_TILEY-1)
           DO ji = 1, jpi
  zfp_wk = pwn(ji,jj,jk) + ABS( pwn(ji,jj,jk) )
  zfm_wk = pwn(ji,jj,jk) - ABS( pwn(ji,jj,jk) )
  zwz(ji,jj,jk) = 0.5 * ( zfp_wk * ptb(ji,jj,jk,jn) + zfm_wk * ptb(ji,jj,jk-1,jn) ) * wmask(ji,jj,jk)
            END DO
        END DO  
    END DO  
END DO
```

Other loop nests are more or less the same, with tiling performed on the centermost loop.

Comment: *"Because for license reasons I cannot post code."* Can't you, at-least, prepare a surrogate [mcve] which would be highly simplified, but would demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Of course @VladimirF, I have edited the post with a simple loop nest example.

Comment: The ifort documentation tells what individual flags are switched on (and off) by such 'groups' as `O2` and `O3`.  (No, don't ask me for a link to the right place in the documentation, that's what search engines are for.)  When this question has interested me in the past I've looked at the impact of individual flags.  It's not clear to me that OP has done the same, or hasn't.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I've searched a lot, but I didn't find the exact O3-exclusive flags enabled by O3. Instead, I found this: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/680174 in which the various HLO optimizations are reported. In my HLO report, only loop fusion, scalar replacement and multiversioning are enabled. However, after various runs with these optimizations disabled, still the result hasn't changed.